# How to view 3D models in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html5-canvas, webgl

how should I make a javascript or any script to visualize 3D models, more exactly I want to view files with extension obj or another.
Pls tell me how can I do that or preferable tell me what script I need to use for that?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use WebGl. But since its hard to use I would highly suggest three.js. It works like a charm. Its easy to use and lets you import custom models. Heres an [example](http://www.pyrus.us/daniel/Other%20Files/WebGL/WebGL-1.htm)